# Displaying the records that are done and not done if we select all

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Currently, my drop down contains only done and not done. Now, I need to add all to my drop down along with done and not done.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="120px" style="margin-left: 5px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlstatus_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Done</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Not Done</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Is your `query` variable just a string variable contains SQL statement? Are you used SqlConnection to connect into DB?

Comment: so what is difficult part over here cant you use in keyword for ReviewStatus

Comment: Basically make the 2nd else a if else and add another 3rd else and don't check for ReviewStatus at all.

Comment: Please use parameters to pass values to sql queries, instead of building those values unescaped into the query. This will prevent problems with embedded quotes which would lead to errors or sql injection attacks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```sql
if (ddl2.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    if (ddl3.SelectedItem.Text == "True")
    {
        query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
    }
    else if (ddl3.SelectedItem.Text == "False")
    {
        query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
    }
else 
    {
       query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
    }
 }
else
{
    if (ddl3.SelectedItem.Text == "True")
    {
        query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
    }
    else if (ddl3.SelectedItem.Text == "False")
    {
        query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
     }
 else
    {
       query = "select M.name,M.ID,M.count,u.ID,sName from tblrecord Mts,data u,Type si where " +
         "u.name='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "' and mts.name=u.id and si.ID= Mts.ID ";
     }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115078/discussion-between-sam-and-abcde).

Comment: Even though the selected values are coming from your database, you should avoid directly constructing SQL queries and instead use parameterised queries, otherwise you are leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.